# JSON to object (typescript, angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript

Rest service gives me JSON with many many fields.

1) is there a way to automatically convert JSON into an object without making the class urself before that (lots of typing)? Convert it, and right away you can read its values?

2) is there a way to get data out of JSON without 1)? For instance, if I just need "name": "John" and don't want to be bothered with the rest of the large JSON file?

Comment: Have you tried JSON.objectify?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse() to convert to an object. You can then filter the object based on your search criteria.

```
var returnedJSON = JSON.parse('[{"name": "jason"}, {"name": "jake"}, {"name": "jill"}]');

var filteredResults = returnedJSON.filter((item) => {
    return item.name === "jason"
});

console.log(filteredResults); // returns {name:"jason"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Yes you can**

Using an interface would perhaps be encouraged instead of classes, unless you'd need a class for something, like having functions.

An interface is more of a help for the IDE and programmer, the IDE can warn you when you are trying to assign wrong values, or wrong types of values. Interfaces do not exists during runtime, as on runtime your code is compiled to plain JS, and in JS there are no interfaces, so all in all you end up with a POJO.

So, when you receive your data, you can simply assign it:

by first mapping:

```
.map(res => res.json());
```

and

```
data: Object = {}; //declare your object

// your subscribe
.subscribe(data => {
   this.data = data;
})
```

As you can see, we have not typed `data` to anything else, but it being an Object.

---

**2. Yes you can extract just certain values**

You mentioned that you are getting an object. Then you can map just a certain value. This can simply be done, by mapping another time:

```
.map(res => res.json());
.map(obj => obj.name)
```

This will just return the `name` from your response.

---

If you instead are receiving an Array, you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). `filter` will return an array of objects that match your condition, `find` will search just for a specific object matching your condition and returning it as an Object. Here are samples:

```
// will return an array of objects, with name matching 'John'
.map(res => res.json().filter(data => data.name == 'John')) 

//will return a single object from an array of objects
.map(res => res.json().find(data => data.name == 'John'))
```

Hope this helps! :)